# Exists Method Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C#

Tags: c#, array, generics, reflection

To determine whether the specified array contains specific element or not, [Array.Exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-5.0) can be used if the given array is one dimensional. I am attempting to implement `Exists` method for multidimensional array cases.

**The experimental implementation**

```
static class MDArrayHelpers
{
    public static bool Exists<T>(Array array, Predicate<T> match)
        where T : unmanaged
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(array, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
        }

        Type elementType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
        if (!elementType.Equals(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
        }

        foreach (var element in array)
        {
            if (match((T)element))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Test cases**

```
Predicate<int> isOne = delegate (int number) { return number == 1; };
Predicate<int> isFour = delegate (int number) { return number == 4; };


Console.WriteLine("One dimensional case");
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Console.WriteLine($"Is one existed in {nameof(array1)}: {Array.Exists(array1, isOne)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is four existed in {nameof(array1)}: {Array.Exists(array1, isFour)}");
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("Two dimensional case");
int[,] array2 = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } };
Console.WriteLine($"Is one existed in {nameof(array2)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array2, isOne)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is four existed in {nameof(array2)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array2, isFour)}");
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("Three dimensional case");
int[,,] array3 = { { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } }, { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } } };
Console.WriteLine($"Is one existed in {nameof(array3)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array3, isOne)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is four existed in {nameof(array3)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array3, isFour)}");
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("Four dimensional case");
int[,,,] array4 = { { { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } }, { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } } }, { { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } }, { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 } } } };
Console.WriteLine($"Is one existed in {nameof(array4)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array4, isOne)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is four existed in {nameof(array4)}: {MDArrayHelpers.Exists(array4, isFour)}");
```

The output of the test code above:

```
One dimensional case
Is one existed in array1: True
Is four existed in array1: False

Two dimensional case
Is one existed in array2: True
Is four existed in array2: False

Three dimensional case
Is one existed in array3: True
Is four existed in array3: False

Four dimensional case
Is one existed in array4: True
Is four existed in array4: False
```

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the LINQ [Enumerable.Any extension Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0).

```
bool result = array4.Cast<int>().Any(x => x == 1);
```

This works for any collection implementing `IEnumerable<T>` and also for enumerations created algorithmically by C# [Iterators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators).

According the the [C# Programming Guide (Arrays)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/):

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>, you can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

This statement is, however, misleading, since we need to cast the array here. Obviously, we only have the access to the non-generic interface `IEnumerable`.

LINQ Extension methods found in the [Enumerable Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-5.0) apply to `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found that `error CS1061: 'int[*,*,*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'int[*,*,*,*]' could be found` occurred in `array4.Any(x => x == 1)`, but `array4.Cast<int>().ToList().Any(x => x == 1)` can be used as a solution.

Comment: The `ToList()` should not be needed

Comment: Please, see also my follow up question: [Is the C# Programming Guide right on pretending that arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66710635/880990).

Comment: @JimmyHu to use the `Any` LINQ extension method, you must import the corresponding namespace with `using System.Linq;`